# Creating a stream to intersect two maps based on their value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method named `getNames`. Its goal: return the names that occur in both of two maps. I tried rewriting this method to a Stream. But, I don't want `testOneNames` to be modified in this operation. How to rebuild it as a stream?

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getNames(Map<String, List<String>> testOneNames, Map<String, List<String>> testSecondNames) {
    Map<String, List<String>> copyTestOneName = new HashMap<>(testOneNames);
    copyTestOneName.values().retainAll(testSecondNames.values());
    return copyTestOneName;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need stream here? Just trying to get your thoughts around benefits you would gain. Also is above code working correctly?

Comment: Code work is correct. When i write code, i often use stream. But, i don't know how use retailAll and removeAll in stream. It's question interesting for me. I assume, this task complete Apache CommonsUtill. But, maybe it not exaclies.

Comment: The values of the map in question would be a `Collection<List<String>>` and you want to retain if the `List<String>` is present as a value in any the other map? Confirming as that's one weird use case in dealing with complete lists and not `key`s of specific `value`s as `String`.

Comment: @Naman totally agree. Voting to close as un-clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getNames(Map<String, List<String>> testOneNames, Map<String, List<String>> testSecondNames) {
    return testOneNames.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> testSecondNames.containsValue(e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```